# Update published self-hosted WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've created an WebApi service, which runs self-hosted on hardly accessible computer. It also is unavailable for remote desktop connection.

So main problem is - how to update the api?
Is there any way, to implement POST `update()` method and somehow stop, update and start service on remote machine?

Is it a bad design, to have "extra" updater service with single method, accepting update package, which will stop/update/launch the main service?
I'm sorry, if the question does not fit for StackOverflow.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be you can configure ftp access and publish api via ftp

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The service can't update itself.